# Accessing Label which is drawn on the worksheet

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I draw a simple label control directly onto the excel worksheet. But I can't seem to find any way to access it via code in the VBA editor. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have drawn an ActiveX label or a Forms label. If it was the first label on the sheet then the following code will pick up the default "label1" name and either objActiveXLabel or objFormslabel will refer to your control

You could also experiment recording macros with the VBA recorder when inserting labels as this will give you pointers to the label type, and how to manipulate the label

```
Dim objActiveXLabel As OLEObject
Dim objFormsLabel As Shape
On Error Resume Next
Set objActiveXLabel = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Label1")
Set objFormsLabel = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Label 1")
On Error GoTo 0
If Not objActiveXLabel Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Found an ActiveX label", vbExclamation
If Not objFormsLabel Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Found an Forms label", vbExclamation
```

Comment: +1 - i took your advice on **experiment recording macors**. Kind of tricky. But it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. Pls note I update the dimensioning of the tests for a "more" correct is Nothing test